# how to get the formidable file attribute name in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Here is my upload form.

```
<form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="myfile"/>
 <br/><br/><br/>
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Now, here is my node js server code that accepts the file upload.
What I am trying to achieve here is that put a check whether the POST request is from **myfile** or not.

Here is the node code.

```
https.createServer(options, function (req, res)
{
    try
    {

        if(req.method === 'POST')
         {
            console.log('got POST request');
            var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
            form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files)
            {
                 console.log(files.myfile);
                 console.log('shreyas');
                 console.log(fields);

                 //console.log('Path',files.myfile.path);
                 var oldpath = files.myfile.path;
                 var newpath = '/home/test/' + files.myfile.name;
                 fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
                 if (err) throw err;
                  res.write('File uploaded Successfully');
                  res.end();
                  });

                // res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
                // res.write('received upload:\n\n');
                // res.end();
                // console.log(fields, files);
           });
           return;
         }
```

I want to put a check whether the request is coming from myfile or not.

Basically, I want to prevent the failure if

```
curl -k -X POST -F "myfile=@/hello.txt" https://11.11.1.3/
```

1. Basically, if instead of myfile something else is given, I want to prevent this request. Where I will I know that myfile request has come or something else?
2. Is there any shortcut to get rid of multiple 
    tags in the html file?
   How can I say that 3 times break in html rather than typing 3 times?

Answer (score 0):

*First problem*

You can check the value of `files.myfile` if it's undefined return error. Something like:

```
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
    if(!files.myfile) {
        res.writeHead(500, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('Not found desired file');
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    //console.log('Path',files.myfile.path);
    var oldpath = files.myfile.path;
    var newpath = '/home/test/' + files.myfile.name;
    fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded Successfully');
        res.end();
    });
});
```

*Second problem*

```css
.submit {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <input type="file" name="myfile"/>
  </div>
  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit"/>
  </div>
</form>
```